# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'stack' in 401 error when awaiting getUser() in nuxt middleware

Tags: frontend, nuxt.js, middleware

I have a nuxtjs frontend with an express backend and i want to use a middleware to determent if the user should be able to navigate to a certain page. Even though it works with onMounted and such the page still loads and i don't want the page to load i just want the user to be sent back to '/'.

Middleware:

```
import { useAuthStore } from "~/stores/user"

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    if (to.path == '/login') {
        const authStore = useAuthStore()
        const asd = await authStore.getUser() // Making this async causes the error.
        if (authStore.user) {
            return navigateTo('/')
        }
    }
})
```

Store:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

interface User {
    id: string,
    username: string,
    email: string,
}

export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
  id: "auth",
  state: () => ({
    authUser: null as User | null,
  }),
  getters: {
    user: (state) => state.authUser,
  },
  actions: {
    async getUser() {
        const resp = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/me', {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
        })

        if (resp.ok) {
            this.authUser = await resp.json()
        } else {
            throw resp.status
        }
    }
  }
});
```